# How to set Databricks widget behavior programmatically?

Tags: widget, databricks

Databricks notebooks allow setting widget behavior from a setting menu: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#configure-widget-settings-1 .

Is there a way to change the "On Widget Change" behavior programmatically?

For context: I don't want to re-run all the cells that are involved with a widget. I'll re-run them manually as needed.